# How to compile a list of dates either weekly or monthly between two dates in excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to set two dates in excel and then select a drop down box for either "weekly" or "monthly". Then I would like to be able to press a button to run a macro that will fill an excel sheet with every date either weekly or monthly.

I am able to currently generate every date between two dates, but would like to be able to change this depending on a drop down box in excel.

```
Sub GenerateDatesH()

Dim FirstDate As Date
Dim LastDate As Date
Dim NextDate As Date
Dim DateOffset As Range
Dim DateIter As Date

FirstDate = Range("startdate").Value
LastDate = Range("enddate").Value
Set DateOffset = Range("StartOfDates")

For DateIter = FirstDate To LastDate
    DateOffset.Value = DateIter
    Set DateOffset = DateOffset.Offset(0, 1)
Next DateIter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer below:

```
'
 Dim sc As Range
 Dim Stdt As Date
 Dim Edt As Date
 Dim dDate As Date
 Dim off As Integer
'
 Stdt = Range("B3") ' start date
 Edt = Range("B4") ' end date
 Set sc = Range("A8") ' start cell
'
 Range("A8").Select
 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
 Selection.ClearContents
'
 off = 0
'
NextDate = Stdt

If Range("B5").Value = "Monthly" Then
For dDate = Stdt To Edt
      If Format(dDate, "dd") = "01" Then
        sc.Offset(0, off) = Format(dDate, "mmmm yyyy")
        off = off + 1
      End If
Next dDate

sc.Resize(1, off).NumberFormat = "mmmm yyyy"

Else
If Range("B5").Value = "Weekly" Then

Do Until NextDate > Edt

    ActiveCell.Value = NextDate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    NextDate = NextDate + 7

Loop
sc.Resize(1, 10000).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy"
End If
End If
'

'
End Sub
```